# Pandas `read_sas` error when loading sas7bdat file with a column with dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, casting, sas

I am having an error with `read_sas` in Pandas:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 372, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas._maybe_cast_from_unit
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.cast_from_unit
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/TSODCGM/workspaces/nordea/pythononzos/src/python/sas_reader_pandas_1.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/u/TSODCGM/workspaces/nordea/nrd_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/u/TSODCGM/workspaces/nordea/nrd_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sasreader.py", line 161, in read_sas
    reader = SAS7BDATReader(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/u/TSODCGM/workspaces/nordea/nrd_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py", line 207, in __init__
    self._get_properties()
  File "/u/TSODCGM/workspaces/nordea/nrd_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py", line 294, in _get_properties
    self.date_created = epoch + pd.to_timedelta(x, unit="s")
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/u/TSODCGM/workspaces/nordea/nrd_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/timedeltas.py", line 211, in to_timedelta
    return _coerce_scalar_to_timedelta_type(arg, unit=unit, errors=errors)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/u/TSODCGM/workspaces/nordea/nrd_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/timedeltas.py", line 219, in _coerce_scalar_to_timedelta_type
    result = Timedelta(r, unit)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 1695, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta.__new__
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 351, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.convert_to_timedelta64
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas._maybe_cast_from_unit
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsTimedelta: Cannot cast 1.3033002481878809e+41 from s to 'ns' without overflow.
```

Output from `pip list`:

```
pandas                 1.5.1.post0
pandas-datareader      0.10.0
```

This is the code:

```py
df = pd.read_sas(url,format = 'sas7bdat')
```

where `url` contains the path for the file.

The problem here is that I can’t avoid casting. I add an image with the table I want to read.

Is there any way to prepare for `read_sas` in Pandas so that I can read the table and assign data types later? I am not able to avoid casting.

Another way would be to assign days or months to the time delta, instead of `ns` so that it doesn’t overflow.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

I’ve tried to use several readers but it’s a SAS sas7bdat file. I need to use `pandas.read_sas` or similar.

I tried to use their

```py
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT

with SAS7BDAT(url) as reader:
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

but it doesn’t work.